# Angular filter of date not working

Tags: angular, angular5, typescript2.0

i want to filter date from a input box
 but it seems it is not working

date from api array: 1979-04-08T16:00:00

data from my input box: Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

how can i accomplished this?

below are my codes for customize search filter pipe:

```
 transform(value: Beneficiary[], filter: Beneficiary): Beneficiary[] {
    var str = '0';
    if (!value || !filter) {
        console.log('no search')
        return value
    }

    if (filter.birthday) {
        //console.log(filter.birthday.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + str.concat((filter.birthday.getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(1, 2) + '-' + str.concat((filter.birthday.getDate()).toString()).substr(1, 2))
        //console.log(str.concat((filter.birthday.getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(1, 2));
        var searchMonth = (filter.birthday.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        var searchDate = filter.birthday.getDate().toString();
        var searchYear = filter.birthday.getFullYear().toString();
        //var completedatenew;

        if (searchMonth.length == 1) {
          searchMonth = str.concat(searchMonth);
        }

        if (searchDate.length == 1) {
          searchDate = str.concat(searchDate);
        }
        var completedate = searchYear + "-" + searchMonth + "-" + searchDate;
        console.log(completedate);
       // var completedatenew = new Date(completedate);
       // filter.birthday = completedatenew;
    }
    //console.log(Beneficiary)
    return value.filter((value: Beneficiary) => this.applyFilter(value, filter));
}


applyFilter(bene: any, filter: any): boolean {
    for (let field in filter) {
        //console.log(typeof filter[field]);
        if (filter[field]) {
            if (typeof filter[field] === 'string') {
                if (bene[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[field].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                    console.log("string false")
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (typeof filter[field] === 'number') {
                if (bene[field] !== filter[field]) {
                    console.log("number false")
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else {
                console.log(bene[field])
                console.log(filter[field])
                console.log("date false");
                return true;
            }

            //else if (typeof filter[field] === 'date') {
                //if (bene[field] !== filter[field]) {
                //    console.log("number false")
                //    return false;
                //}
            //}
        }
    }
    //console.log('returning as true')
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should pass the values as arguments not the object. Whenever the values in the object changes the filter pipe doesn't recognize that change.
So pass in values directly, in this case birth date.

Comment: how can i accomplish that? the values are from my api passed to an array. my problem is how can my input value from my filter matches my data stored in the array?

Comment: how can i accomplish that? the values are from my api passed to an array. my problem is how can my input value from my filter matches my data stored in the array? this api data is from date format. as this my input data is data but not the same format. date from api array: 1979-04-08T16:00:00

data from my input box: Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

Comment: i cant equate this 1979-04-08T16:00:00 to this Sun Apr 08 1979 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time) both of them are in date data type